# Display common data only one in the table by g:each Grails

Tags: grails, html-table, each

I am using Grails 2.3.4 and I have list as following in controller

`test = [[item 2, it2, 15.0, 1], [item 2, it2, 20.0, 2], [item 2, it2, 25.0, 3], [item 2, it2, 30.0, 4], [item 2, it2, 35.0, 5], [item3, code 3, 4.0, 1], [item3, code 3, 33.0, 2], [item3, code 3, 5.0, 3], [item3, code 3, 445.0, 4], [item3, code 3, 55.0, 5]]`

I want to display it in the table in the following way:

```
Item name   Item Code   Price Level Price
item 2        it2          1    15.0
              it2          2    20.0
              it2          3    25.0
              it2          4    30.0
              it2          5    35.0
item3        code 3        1    4.0
             code 3        2    33.0
             code 3        3    5.0
             code 3        4    445.0
             code 3        5    55.0
```

I am trying it in the following way please help,

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item name</th>
        <th>Item Code</th>
        <th>Price Level</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <g:each var="itms"  in="${items}">


        <tr>
            <td>${itms[0]}</td>
            <td>${itms[1]}</td>

            <td>${itms[3]}</td>
            <td>${itms[2]}</td>

        </tr>
    </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what exactly does your controller action return?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you must do:

```
def index() {
    def someItems=[
                ["item 2", "it2", 15.0, 1],
                ["item 2", "it2", 20.0, 2],
                ["item 2", "it2", 25.0, 3],
                ["item 2", "it2", 30.0, 4],
                ["item 2", "it2", 35.0, 5],
                ["item3", "code 3", 4.0, 1],
                ["item3", "code 3", 33.0, 2],
                ["item3", "code 3", 5.0, 3],
                ["item3", "code 3", 445.0, 4],
                ["item3","code 3",55.0,5]
            ] 
  [items:someItems]
}
```

Comment: i want to display it in the table but how to remove multiple values and display only one in the table?The one you did is the controller code but how to display it in the table?